# why i cant use template tags in django

Tags: django, templates, tags

I tried to loop the link and name in the list but it's not working,
can someone explain to me why it is not working?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m91AW.png)

Comment: please share your question as code, don't share images please.

Comment: sorry I'm new here

Comment: you're welcome, I know that's why I told you, Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you don't pass your context data to your html file, pass it by doing this:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        "nav": [
            ["/", "Home"],
            ["/about", "About"],
            ["/blog", "Blog"],
        ],
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Comment: you're welcome, please accept answers if they're right, by doing this others know that this question has been answered.